# DB Error SQLSTATE[42S02]

Tags: magento2, database, error, sql

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'mavikmarine_l2li.m_catalog_product_flat_1_tmp_indexer' doesn't exist,
>   query was: UPDATE `m_catalog_product_flat_1_tmp_indexer` AS `et` 
>   INNER JOIN `m_catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id =
>   et.entity_id  INNER JOIN `m_catalog_product_entity_text` AS `t` ON
>   t.entity_id = e.entity_id AND t.attribute_id=181 AND t.store_id = 1
>   AND t.value IS NOT NULL SET `et`.`codazon_custom_tab` = `t`.`value`

Comment: Sorry, cut out half my email. This error came after changing to a flat category structure. Similar error happened a while ago, but went away after I set it back. I recently tired again and still get this error even after reverting the setting.

Comment: m_catalog_product_flat_1_tmp_indexer  - table not exist in database